# Rope material stretching along long faces

Tags: materials, uv, node-editor

Trying to make a rope material. Granted I am still learning this, but my result seems to be stretching in strange ways....

This is how the UV is unwrapped and this are the nodes being used
[image: https://gyazo.com/495b630d8be1c4f163103bb69e4a4d3c]
[image]

any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hello :). It seems you stretched some parts of your rope, without updating the UV map.  Simply unwrap again. Also, no need for so many UV seams, it'll only make it harder to line up the texture :).

Comment: Yea actually this snapshot is immediately after a fresh unwrapping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scale your UVs where it is stretched, you can do this by selecting the stretched faces and then seeing what vertices are highlighted int he UV view, you then press 's' to scale and then 'x' or 'y' to scale on the axis you need, in your case it looks like the 'y' axis.

That should fix it though not a real fix as you have to do it each time you edit the mesh, you have an issue where you have marked all your edges as seams, it's supposed to be like Origami, this is why a cube unfolds to a T shape rather than four squares (UV islands as they call them). Seams are essentially cuts that you would add to the flat paper to turn them into a 3D shape (remember textures are 2D and models are 3D,it's just turning that 3D shape back into a 2D one). Try removing some seams to make less islands. I would say that you need a maximum of three. One for each end of the rope and one for the length of the rope spanning all the way around.

Like seen here:
[image]
This one I actually made it one UV island by removing two edges from being marked as a seam in that example (You see how we are back to that T shape? Even though it is upside down):
[image]

I highly suggest watching this playlist, it goes into the UV unwrapping too! I know it says intermediate but don't let that put you off... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tdUxzhEy_E&list=PLjEaoINr3zgHJVJF3T3CFUAZ6z11jKg6a&index=1

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm not sure why I was stuck so much on this one, and didn't see reducing the number of seems as a solution. This worked perfectly with a little scaling in the mapping node. I did take this one step further by making applying follow active quads on the islands.

Comment: Basically when you add seams to every edge, every face becomes scaled to fit the UV area for the best use of texel space. Otherwise you have loads of UV pixels that are not bing used and are a waste of data. By adding the least amount of seams, it constrains that scaling and will make sure that the model is closer to 1:1 ratio on the UV.